# How should I ground a heat pump capacitor?

Tags: central-heating

Where do I attach ground wire on capacitor that has no designated ground connector?[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's better to ask about your actual challenge. Seems like a grounded capacitor couldn't... capacitate. They usually have just two terminals. If anything, the body is grounded through the mounting strap.

Comment: Ha, Excellent question. After I put a new capacitor in yesterday; I had ice on heat pump coils for the first time ever. The only variable was new capacitor. I’m brainstorming cause of icing. I assumed band attachment did grounding but also know there are a lot of connectors on the newer capacitors. Still to check are wrong connections to motor or maybe I was provided wrong size capacitor. Other possibilities appreciated. The unit is 33 years old and Still very efficient. Trying to nurse it through 1 more winter:).

Comment: @isherwood safety ground shouldn't be a player in anything electrical. Anything other than safety ground shouldn't have bare wires.  The only reaon to ground that cap is to keep its case from being energized by an internal short.

Answer (score 1):

The metal strap that holds the cap in place is the ground. You have 3 connections so that is a dual element cap it has 2 capacitors internally normal values are like 5uf & 45uf  370-400v . 
1 terminal will be common “C” and normally one will have a “S” start and the other “R” run , with a metal can the case is grounded by the strap on every system I have worked on.
Note the strap for your cap is just to the left in the photo.
I did remember some caps are labeled “c”  common and “H” for the compressor “f” fan this is where a dual element cap is used for starting 2 different motors but they can be used interchangeably if the ratings are the same the 45uf element is for starting the compressor and the 5uf element is for the fan or in some cases the run of the compressor.

Answer (score 0):

Electrically, grounding the capacitor is not needed, but it should be secured
in place so that vibrations do not cause damage.

One way would be to wrap a length of metal strap around to form a "P clamp" and bolt or screw it to a suitable mounting point.

Comment: Grounding is required by almost every manufacturer. Remember the cap creates a phase shift and this electrical noise adds to the RFI created by the system grounding the case reduces the radiated RFI.

Comment: radiated electrical noise from an induction motor?  pull the other one it's got bells on!